# Limits approaching from both sides go to infinity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$. Prove that we then have $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = \infty$ from the definitions using epsilon-delta methods.

Comment: Can you show us your working?

Comment: Sure. $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if for every $B \in \mathbf{R}$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $x - a < \delta$ implies that $f(x) > B$. Similarly, $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if for every $B \in \mathbf{R}$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $a - x < \delta$ implies that $f(x) > B$. Now, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if for every $B \in \mathbf{R}$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ implies that $f(x) > B$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. If $x - a > 0$, then $x - a > a - x$, so $|x - a| < \delta$ implies that both $x - a$ and $a - x$ are less than $\delta$. Similarly for $a - x > 0$. So you take $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ to be the values of $\delta$ for each case and you take the min of those to establish the property. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$. So for all $M > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a|<\delta$ implies $f(x) > M$.

Now, look at $|x-a|<\delta$. In other words, try to work with $-\delta < x-a < \delta$.

It may help to recall the definitions of $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$. Show how you will get to those definitions, to establish the fact that $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$.